# /dev/ttyUSB does not show

Tags: nanopi

I am using nano pi neo board.

and the Linux kernel 4.14

but when i login the board, i only see /dev/tty* and /dev/ttyS* files,  /dev/ttyUSB file is not shown in /dev/ director.

how can i fix this problem ? How to config the kernel  and how to config the dtb file?

but when i login the board, i only see /dev/tty* and /dev/ttyS* files,  /dev/ttyUSB file is not shown in /dev/ director.

how can i fix this problem ? How to config the kernel  and how to config the dtb file?